# Sticky Comments

Tags: comments

How can I have sticky comments? I am trying to make it so that I can make a comment go above all the other comments. Is this possible? If so what code can I use to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was curious about any existing plugins and searched the plugin directory. There exists an old *Sticky Comments* plugin, I'm not related to it. It seems to use a sticky meta key.

It uses a LEFT JOIN query but creates it's own version of the whole `comments_template()` core function, to override the current query. One would need to update that custom function, if the core function changes. This was most likely done because of the hard coded SQL queries that this function contained.

Now, in WordPress 4.3.1,  the `comments_template()` function only contains a single `get_comments()` call and we can therefore use a single filter instead to override it.

Now here are few ideas how to do that:

### Method #1

We could use the *sticky* comment type to mark the sticky comments.

Then we could use the `pre_get_comments` hook to adjust the ordering:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'wpse_comment_stickies_v1' ); 

function wpse_comment_stickies_v1( \WP_Comment_Query $q )
{
    // Only run it once
    remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Modify the ordering, so sticky comments are at the top
    $q->query_vars[ 'orderby'] = [
        'comment_type'      => 'DESC',
        'comment_date_gmt'  => 'ASC',
        'comment_ID'        => 'ASC'
    ];

}
```

where you've to add the line:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'wpse_comment_stickies_v1' );
```

just before the  `comments_template()` call in your theme.

The array ordering was added in WordPress 4.2 but the [Codex on `WP_Comment_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) doesn't mention it.

### Method #2

This one is similar as in #1, but here we use the `comments_clauses` filter to modify the ordering of the comments:

```
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_comment_stickies_v2' ); 

function wpse_comment_stickies_v2( $clauses )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Only run it once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Modify the ordering, so sticky comments are at the top                
    $clauses['orderby'] = $wpdb->comments . '.comment_type DESC, ' . $clauses['orderby'];

    return $clauses;
}
```

### Method #3

We could use the comment meta as well. If we mark the sticky comments with the `sticky` comment meta, then we can modify the ordering with:

```
add_action( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_stickies_v3' ); 

function wpse_stickies_v3( $clauses )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // LEFT JOIN the comments table and the comments meta table
    $clauses['join'] .= " 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->commentmeta} wpsecm 
        ON ( wpsecm.comment_id = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_ID AND wpsecm.meta_key = 'sticky' ) ";

    // Order by the meta key 
    $clauses['orderby'] = 'wpsecm.meta_key DESC, ' . $clauses['orderby'];
    return $clauses;
}
```

### Method #4

This is similar to #3, but where we only modify the `orderby` clause:

```
add_action( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_stickies_v4' ); 

function wpse_stickies_v4( $clauses )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = [];
    $orderby[] = "
        (   SELECT COUNT( comment_ID ) 
            FROM {$wpdb->commentmeta} wpsecm 
            WHERE wpsecm.comment_id = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_ID 
                AND wpsecm.meta_key = 'sticky' 
        ) DESC ";
    $orderby[] = $clauses['orderby'];
    $clauses['orderby'] = join( ',', $orderby );

    return $clauses;
}
```

### Notes

Sometimes I wish there was an argument filter in `comments template()`, to make it easier to only target  it's query, because you don't want to mess with other `get_comments()` calls e.g. in the widgets.

I created a [ticket #34442](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34442) with some suggestions, that would make it easier to target this query from a plugin.

In WordPress 4.4 the `get_comments()` call will be replaced with:

```
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $comment_args );
```

but that will not change much here, since `get_comments()` is just a simple `WP_Comment_Query` wrapper.

I haven't mentioned here how one could modify the UI to mark the *sticky* comments.
But you can e.g. check out this old plugin, I mentioned earlier, for ideas on that matter.

Comment: You do have a lot of free time thinking of coding ideas on a Sunday afternoon when you should be taking a nap to recharge for the dreaded [Monday Monday](https://youtube.com/watch?v=iIo8_bMFwxs) ;-)

Comment: I guess some questions are more sticky than others ;-)  @PieterGoosen

Comment: You're welcome ps: I created a ticket with some suggestions (see updated answer) and skimmed through the trunk of WordPress 4.4. @matthew

Comment: Couldn't resists myself giving this a thumbs up :)